# (Phoenix.ActionClauseError) could not find a matching

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

It seems to be a param mismatch but I have looked over my router, model and controller over and over and cannot see anything wrong. Any help greatly appreciated.

CREATE CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
  def create(conn, %{"events" => event_params}) do
    IO.puts "in create"
    changeset = Events.changeset(%Events{}, event_params)
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _events} ->
       events = Repo.all(Events)
       render conn, "index.json", events: events
    end
  end
```

MODEL:

```
defmodule AMHK.Events do
  use AMHK.Web, :model

  schema "events" do
    field :address, :string
    field :author, :string
    field :body, :string
    field :front_page, :boolean
    field :image, :string
    field :link, :string
    field :location, :string
    field :published, :boolean
    field :time_date, :string
    field :title, :string

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:address, :author, :body, :front_page, :image, :link, 
      :location, :published, :time_date, :title])
  end
end
```

ROUTER:

```
  scope "/api", AMHK do
    pipe_through :api

    get "/events", EventsController, :index
    get "/events/:id", EventsController, :show
    post "/events", EventsController, :create
    delete "/events/:id", EventsController, :delete
    put "/events/:id", EventsController, :update
  end
```

REACT FORM SUBMITTING:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      address: '',
      author: '',
      body: '',
      front_page: false,
      image: '',
      link: '',
      location: '',
      published: false,
      time_date: 'now',
      title: 'ddddd'
    }
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
    console.log("hi")
  }

  handleChange (event) {
    // let newState = {};
    // newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    // this.setState(newState);

    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/events', {
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      data: {
        events: {
          address: this.state.address,
          author: this.state.author,
          body: this.state.body,
          front_page: this.state.front_page,
          image: this.state.image,
          link: this.state.link,
          location: this.state.location,
          published: this.state.published,
          time_date: this.state.time_date,
          title: this.state.title
        }
      }
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
    <form onSubmit = {
      this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    } >
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Title</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value = {this.state.title}
            name="title"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Body</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value = {this.state.body}
            name="body"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">
          image
        </label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text" placeholder="Enter Image URL"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value = {this.state.image}
            name="image"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">link</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value = {this.state.link}
            name = "link"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Author</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value = {this.state.author}
            name="author"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">location</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value = {this.state.location}
            name = "location"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Address</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="text"
            onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            value = {this.state.address}
            name = "address"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Published?</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            checked = {this.state.published}
            name = "published"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="field">
        <label className="label">Put on front page?</label>
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            type="checkbox"
            onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            checked = {this.state.front_page}
            name = "front_page"
          />
        </div>
      </div>

      <button
        type="submit"
        value="Submit"
        className="button is-primary"
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
    )
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Expecting a successful post and save to my db. I get this 400 error and this in the console:

```
(Phoenix.ActionClauseError) could not find a matching AMHK.EventsController.create clause
```

**UPDATE PER SUGGESTIONS. NO ERRORS BUT EMPTY DB RECORD IS CREATED:**

```
[debug] QUERY OK source="events" db=4.2ms
SELECT e0."id", e0."address", e0."author", e0."body", e0."front_page", e0."image", e0."link", e0."location", e0."published", e0."time_date", e0."title", e0."inserted_at", e0."updated_at" FROM "events" AS e0 []
[info] Sent 200 in 5ms
[info] POST /api/events
in create
[debug] Processing with AMHK.EventsController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"events" => %{"address" => "k ", "author" => "k", "body" => "k", "front_page" => true, "image" => "k", "link" => "k", "location" => "k", "published" => false, "time_date" => "now", "title" => "a"}, "headers" => %{"Content-Type" => "application/json"}}
  Pipelines: [:api]
inside changes
[debug] QUERY OK db=2.9ms
INSERT INTO "events" ("inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "id" [{{2017, 12, 11}, {16, 2, 25, 497379}}, {{2017, 12, 11}, {16, 2, 25, 497390}}]
[debug] QUERY OK source="events" db=0.5ms
SELECT e0."id", e0."address", e0."author", e0."body", e0."front_page", e0."image", e0."link", e0."location", e0."published", e0."time_date", e0."title", e0."inserted_at", e0."updated_at" FROM "events" AS e0 []
[info] Sent 200 in 4ms
```

IO.inspect params:

```
%{"events" => %{"address" => "k", "author" => "k", "body" => "k",
    "front_page" => false, "image" => "k", "link" => "k", "location" => "k",
    "published" => true, "time_date" => "now", "title" => "ddddd"},
  "headers" => %{"Content-Type" => "application/json"}}
[debug] QUERY OK db=22.4ms
INSERT INTO "events" ("inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING "id" [{{2017, 12, 11}, {19, 21, 33, 179707}}, {{2017, 12, 11}, {19, 21, 33, 179718}}]
[debug] QUERY OK source="events" db=9.7ms decode=0.1ms
SELECT e0."id", e0."address", e0."author", e0."body", e0."front_page", e0."image", e0."link", e0."location", e0."published", e0."time_date", e0."title", e0."inserted_at", e0."updated_at" FROM "events" AS e0 []
[info] Sent 200 in 33ms
```

Comment: Can you post the source of the form that submits to `create`?

Comment: @Dogbert I bet the issue is `def create(conn, %{"events" => event_params}) do` should read `def create(conn, %{} = event_params) do`.

Comment: @mudasobwa The form code should make that clear. Using a changeset there should post to `%{"events" => event_params}`. See the files scaffolding generates.

Comment: React form submitting added to the question above.

Comment: @AbeKinney I think the second argument to `axios.post` is just the data and the config should be in third? See https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases.

Comment: this does the same at the first line of the create suggestion - post errors no longer a problem but the db entry is all nulls. stack trace above.

Comment: @AbeKinney Can you add `IO.inspect params` to `changeset` and post the output? The "Parameters: " value looks fine to me and this should be working.

Comment: added above after puts of "PARAMS "

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `axios.post` is just the data. The headers and other options should be in the third argument. Changing your `axios.post` call to the following should fix your problem:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/events', {
  events: {
    address: this.state.address,
    ...
  },
}, {headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}})
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the way I had nested the data in my post. I was putting it in side data and events. I changed the method signature and it is fixed and writing to the db as expected:

Changing the method signature to this makes it work:

```
  def create(conn, %{"data" => %{"events" => event_params}}) do
```

Comment: And now you get the right values inserted into the DB which you weren't getting with my answer (as you said in the comments)?